# How to create a new instance react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to create a new instance of this component and want to change the title desc and image for new the instance, but I am getting the error as

**Error :**

> ReferenceError: product is not defined

```
function Ads(product) {
 return(
   <div className = "row" id="user-ads">
      <div className = "col-sm-6 col-md-5">
          <div className = "thumbnail">
          <img src = "img/img1.jpg" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail" />
          </div>
          <div className = "caption">
          <div className="border">
             <h3>{product.title}</h3>
          <p>{product.desc}</p>  
          <button className = "btn btn-primary" role = "button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-detail">View Details
          </button>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
          );
    }
    var Newad = new Ads(product);
```

Comment: code looks `foreign` to reactjs

Answer (score 1):

That's not a React component. This is one way to write a component. There is ES6 syntax, but I won't bother posting it because it could confuse you.

```
// Include React 
var React = require('react');

var Ads = React.createClass({

    render: function(){

        return(
            <div>
              <h1>I'm a Ad!</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = Ads;
```